# Node.js calculate imprecise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do payment with Node.js, but find:

```
4.9 * 100 = 490.00000000000006
```

I can't stand this situation sometimes. How can I solve it?

Comment: Unaware of float math? Ever heard of Bignum? If working with currency, how about working in cents?

Comment: @elclanrs alright, I know the cents way, I just curious about if there is a npm to solve the problem.